# get all values in where clause

Tags: php, mysql

Am facing troubles in this code, i just want to get all data from table row if the user selected "show all" from the select drop menu.

here is the select menu !

so, this menu grab data from this table, but if he selects All, what is the suitable code to echoing in between option value :)

```
<b>speciality:</b>  <select id="main_mav" name="speciality">
<option value="none">Select speciality:</option>
<option value=""> All specialities </option>
<?php

        $result = mysql_query('SELECT speciality FROM visits') or die(mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$row['speciality'].'">'.$row['speciality'].'</option>';
        }
?>
</select><br />
```

That's the Submit form !

```
if ($region=="All regions" ){


              $region=$_POST['""'];  
            }
            else ( $region=$_POST['region']);

            $date1 =$_POST['from_date'];
            $date2 = $_POST['to_date'];
            $product=$_POST['product'];
            $speciality=$_POST['speciality'];
            $type=$_POST['visit_type'];

sql="SELECT id, customer_name, seller_1_name, seller_2_name FROM visits Where (speciality ='$speciality') AND (visit_type ='$type') AND (product ='$product') AND (region ='$region') AND (visit_date BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2')";
$result=mysql_query($sql); ## This line is new.
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

What's the correct code to enter if user selected " show all in drop menu " ?!

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.**  You *really* should be using prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 2):

You really need to sanitize your inputs, at least with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)!

On to your actual question: just check if `$speciality` is empty, and generate a different query without the `(speciality ='$speciality')` condition.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated and PDO should be used, or at least mysqli_* functions

Comment: I know, but explaining how to change the whole OP code to use PDO is far beyond the scope of the question. That's why I said "at least".

Comment: +1 for finding the condition so fast. :) Also, @AlanFoster seeing as OP is using the `mysql_` commands which are also deprecated, I don't see problem with that. Seems like he is still learning as this is a basic question, so I'd guess security isn't the highest priority atm. =]

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is not deprecated

Comment: Oh yes, wrong wording, `mysql_` commands are not deprecated, just highly unrecommended. They're still available as to support older applications.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Apologies, you are correct. They are currently not deprecated, but they are within the scope of deprecation for PHP6 ?

Comment: PHP6 was ruined a long time ago, put on indefinite haitus.

Comment: Nothing seems to be actually deprecated, but the old `mysql` driver is at least [officially "not reccomended"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). The manual also mentions "long term deprecation announced".

Comment: By the time it's deprecated, PHP will be the new Perl. Everybody will be using Node / Nginx /MongoDb

Answer (score 0):

Since your HTML referenced 'specialties' and your PHP referenced 'regions' I'm gonna just stick with 'regions', but here's the idea.

```
    if ($region=="All regions" ){
        $sql = 'SELECT id, customer_name, seller_1_name, seller_2_name, FROM visits';
    } else {
        $region     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['region']);
        $date1      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from_date']);
        $date2      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['to_date']);
        $product    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product']);
        $speciality = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['speciality']);
        $type       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['visit_type']);
        $sql        = "SELECT id, customer_name, seller_1_name, seller_2_name FROM visits Where (speciality ='$speciality') AND (visit_type ='$type') AND (product ='$product') AND (region ='$region') AND (visit_date BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2')";
    }

$result = mysql_query($sql); ## This line is new.
$num    = mysql_numrows($result);
$row    = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```